# Using a loop in Javascript that modifies a different variable in each iteration

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, api

I have seen some variations on this question asked in other languages, but I am working in Javascript (specifically, with Typescript in Angular). **I am working with an API that returns substantial amounts of data and does not allow for filtered submissions.**  Specifically, it returns all statistics for all players who appeared at least one time in a given season in a professional sports league.   So we're talking about a JSON with 1500 objects that each have 35 or so keys.    One of these keys is an ID number for the team the player belonged to.

Then I have a second query (from another endpoint), which lists all the teams in the league and their ID numbers.

The processing type for sorting and filtering the entire statistical data via pipes for display is excessive (a team filter, various column sort filters, etc), so **what I would like to do is break the data out categorically into smaller arrays by team**, since the data server won't do this for me.

So roughly what I am trying to do is something like this (which is more pseudo-code than actual code, but should illustrate my goal).

```
ArrayOfTeams.ForEach(TeamID => let ArrayOfTeam${teamID}Stats =
ArrayOfLeagueStats.Filter(player => player["Team_Played_For"] === TeamID)
```

I would of course declare these variables outside the loop so that I could then grab the correct array for queries about a specific team.

I understand that in practical application this sort of function would probably be performed in another manner (likely by bringing this data into a server that then allowed filtered queries of the data). I am a student and do not currently have access to that sort of setup and am attempting to do this client-side.

**The alternative is to make specific coded functions for each team's ID (they're static) and invoke all 30 of them, but it seems like there has to be a better way to do this**, and that the ability to cycle variables in an iterator would be a useful function in other circumstances.

Comment: And why can't you use `ArrayOfTeam[teamID].stats` or `ArrayOfTeamStats[teamID]`? What is the reason that you want/need to use individual variables per team?

Comment: I'm trying to improve response time.  Let's imagine that I take this data and lay it out the way you'd see in the real world: with a team leaderboard that can be sorted ascending/descending in any given statistic, where players with less than x appearances are filtered out (and that may be a togglable value that the user can adjust).

This involves passing this array through multiple pipes on pageload (team filter pipe, appearances filter pipe, sort asc/desc pipe) and then re-calculating it any time the user changes an input.   The processing delay is noticable, but gone w/ a single team

Comment: Yes, but why do you need individual variables for that? Instead of that, you could use individual properties of an object, and pass the value that is stored in that property around. Performance-wise there would be no difference between storing it in individual variables or as parameters.

Comment: You will not improve response time this way. The bottleneck is the transmission of the data from server to client.

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow what you're suggesting or how it would work without forcing the processing to go through all 1500 objects in the array each time the user changes an input.

It does occur to me I could probably have something like a 'currentViewedTeam' array as a shallow copy of the filtered array and then transform that, forcing it to only do the full object once (though that wouldn't fix initial page load).

Comment: Trin, the initial query is very laggy (several seconds), but the data is only updated daily, so my idea was to make the API call immediately (prior to the user making selections about which team to view), and then transforming the return client-side based on input.   This would hide the query delay behind time the user is interacting with the page.